# How to subset based on multiple variables in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Good afternoon,

I am trying to filter a data frame that includes 94 different items and how much they were sold in different hours, by the top 15 items sold overall, from the data below:

```
structure(list(Time = c("07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "08"), 
Item = c("Bread", "Coffee", "Medialuna", "Pastry", "Toast", 
"Afternoon with the baker"), Transactions = c(2L, 13L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
Time = c("07", "08"), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I already know the 15 most popular items by name ("Coffee", "Tea", "Bread", etc.), and I have tried to subset the data frame using the code below:

```
SalesPerTimePerItem <- subset(SalesPerTimePerItem,
                          Item == c("Coffee",
                                    "Tea",
                                    "Bread",
                                    "Cake",
                                    "Pastry",
                                    "Sandwich",
                                    "Medialuna",
                                    "Hot chocolate",
                                    "Cookies",
                                    "Brownie",
                                    "Farm House",
                                    "Muffin",
                                    "Alfajores",
                                    "Juice",
                                    "Soup"))
```

But I have received this error:

```
In Item == c("Coffee", "Tea", "Bread", "Cake", "Pastry", "Sandwich",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have also tried another method below:

```
SalesPTPI <- SalesPTPI[SalesPTPI$Item %in% c("Coffee",
                                         "Tea",
                                         "Bread",
                                         "Cake",
                                         "Pastry",
                                         "Sandwich",
                                         "Medialuna",
                                         "Hot chocolate",
                                         "Cookies",
                                         "Brownie",
                                         "Farm House",
                                         "Muffin",
                                         "Alfajores",
                                         "Juice",
                                         "Soup")]
```

But got the error:

```
Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 3 but subscript `i` has size 631.
```

My aim, with this data, is to create a barplot like the one I have linked below:

[image]

but with different objects:

```
(x = Time, y = Transactions, fill = Item)
```

How I can filter out only the 'Coffee', etc., responses from the data frame included at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **first example** is wrong, because `==` is used to match against single values, not a vector.

To fix it, substitute `==` with `%in%`

---

Your **second example** is wrong, because `df[df$var %in% vals]` selects columns, not rows.

To fix it, add a comma after the expression `df[df$var %in% vals,]`

Comment: I know that they are wrong, that's why I'm asking for help on this website, which is for coding help.

Why was it necessary to edit my post as such? You are the first person to force edit one of my posts and some of the corrections aren't even correct. Do you do this to everyone's posts? I am new to SO, so please explain if this is normal behaviour.

Thanks for the help.

(Sorry if this reads as rude or confrontational, I'm simply genuinely curious).

Comment: Editing posts to make them clearer is standard practice. Which of my corrections seemed incorrect to you?

Comment: 'How I can filter...' is not correct, grammatically. The correct version is, 'How can I filter...'

Comment: This was not introduced by my change, as your version was: "So, any idea how I can filter", I simply made it shorter. You can check the effects of my changes by clicking on the small text above my avatar within your post, where it says "edited 50 mins ago"

Comment: Yes, using 'So, any idea...' makes that syntax grammatically correct. You have edited a grammatically correct statement and transformed it into a grammatically incorrect statement. If your edit has resulted in the sentence being incorrect, that is not my fault as the original author, but yours as the editor. You should proof read your edits, that's all.

Comment: Thanks, English is not my native language so I can make mistakes. You can also edit your own post of course, even after someone else has edited them. You can revert the edits too if you don't like them.

Comment: I agree with all the other edits, you made the post a lot clearer, so thank you. Also, thank you for answering my question. Have a nice day!